# PHP json_encode trouble with accents on OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, json, yii, character-encoding, osx-elcapitan

I am developing a php website with the **Yii Framework** on my local machine:

- OS X El Capitan
- PHP 5.6.6
- Apache/2.4.16

I'm reading some data from database and trying to json_encode them but, when these data contain some accented letters, **json_encode fails and returns false**.

I also tried to use **iconv()** to convert the problematic strings but also iconv return false with the following error: **Detected an illegal character in input string**.

I am sure the problem is not related to database data (I tried to access the same database remotely using a Linux machine with PHP 5.6.7 and the same code works great).

The problem seems to be in some encoding setting I am forgetting.

Comment: You need to post code for people to be able to help.

Comment: make sure you're using the **SAME** charset throughout the entire rendering pipeline. there's no point in having (say) utf-8 tables in your db, if the connection to the db is using something else, like latin-1. that'll corrupt the unicode. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through